# Pandas Logical Operators and .isin yielding different results

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently doing the second excercise of the [pandas learning from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/pandas) which uses the [wine reviews](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/zynicide/wine-reviews) dataset.

The task is to select all wines from either Australia or New Zeeland that have a rating of at least 95 points.

Why do I get different results with the following two statements, i.e. why are the wines of New Zeeland missing in the first one?

`reviews[((reviews.country == 'New Zeeland') | (reviews.country == 'Australia')) & (reviews.points >=95)]`

yields 47 entries, while

`reviews[(reviews.country.isin(['New Zeeland', 'Australia'])) & (reviews.points >= 95)]`

yields 49.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which csv file you use?

Comment: winemag-data-130k-v2.csv